# Invalid passport authentication even after sending right token of Microsoft Graph

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, adal, passport-azure-ad

I've a Node.js API which is protected using passport-azure-ad's BearerStrategy.

I've another Client App which provides me a token to access Microsoft Graph.
I've used that token to access Microsoft Graph and its working properly.

But when I use the same token to authenticate in my API its throwing me this error.

Response body: Unauthorized
Response status: 401

This is my configuration of passport to protect the API

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const passport = require('passport');
const OIDCBearerStrategy = require('passport-azure-ad').BearerStrategy;

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(morgan(':method :url :date :remote-addr :status :response-time'));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const passportConfiguration = {
  clientID: <<<Application ID>>>,
  identityMetadata: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<<<Tenant ID>>>/.well-known/openid-configuration',
  audience: 'https://graph.microsoft.com', // I've even tried setting this to my App ID URI of Application registration
  validateIssuer: true, // if you have validation on, you cannot have users from multiple tenants sign in
  passReqToCallback: false,
  loggingLevel: 'info',
};

const OIDCStrategy = new OIDCBearerStrategy(passportConfiguration, (token, done) => {
  console.log('Verifying the User...');
  console.log('Access Token:', token);

  done(null, token);
});

passport.use(OIDCStrategy);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('Welcome!');
});

app.get('/users', passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer', {
  session: false,
}), (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('Take users...');
});

app.listen(8082, () => {
  console.log('App is running on http://localhost:8082');
});
```

So when I hit the homepage '/' it's showing the proper response as it's not covered with the security layer of passport.

But when I hit http://localhost:8082/users
with header: 
Authorization: Bearer <<>>

It's returning Unauthorized with status 401.
But I've tried to access Microsoft Graph using same token and I'm getting the response.

These are the passsport log:

```
{"name":"AzureAD: Metadata Parser","hostname":"Deadman-INC","pid":5036,"level":30,"msg":"Parsing JSON retreived from the endpoint","time":"2019-01-15T07:54:36.374Z","v":0}
{"name":"AzureAD: Metadata Parser","hostname":"Deadman-INC","pid":5036,"level":30,"msg":"Request to update the Open ID Connect Metadata","time":"2019-01-15T07:54:36.378Z","v":0}
{"name":"AzureAD: Bearer Strategy","hostname":"Deadman-INC","pid":5036,"level":30,"msg":"In Strategy.prototype.authenticate: received metadata","time":"2019-01-15T07:54:36.637Z","v":0}
{"name":"AzureAD: Bearer Strategy","hostname":"Deadman-INC","pid":5036,"level":30,"msg":"In Strategy.prototype.authenticate: we will validate the options","time":"2019-01-15T07:54:36.640Z","v":0}
{"name":"AzureAD: Bearer Strategy","hostname":"Deadman-INC","pid":5036,"level":30,"msg":"In Strategy.prototype.authenticate: access_token is received from request header","time":"2019-01-15T07:54:36.643Z","v":0}
{"name":"AzureAD: Bearer Strategy","hostname":"Deadman-INC","pid":5036,"level":30,"msg":"In Strategy.prototype.jwtVerify: token is decoded","time":"2019-01-15T07:54:36.649Z","v":0}
{"name":"AzureAD: Metadata Parser","hostname":"Deadman-INC","pid":5036,"level":30,"msg":"working on key","time":"2019-01-15T07:54:36.655Z","v":0}
{"name":"AzureAD: Bearer Strategy","hostname":"Deadman-INC","pid":5036,"level":30,"msg":"PEMkey generated","time":"2019-01-15T07:54:36.666Z","v":0}
{"name":"AzureAD: Bearer Strategy","hostname":"Deadman-INC","pid":5036,"level":30,"msg":"authentication failed due to: In Strategy.prototype.jwtVerify: cannot verify token","time":"2019-01-15T07:54:36.675Z","v":0}
```

Could anyone help me out in this?

Comment: Not familiar with BearerStrategy, could you tell me why you consider the access token used to access ms graph will be able to authenticate in your API?

Comment: To reword Joy's comment, an access token for MS Graph API cannot be used as authentication for your API. You need to acquire an access token for your API in the front-end.

Comment: I don't want to add one more authentication token handler using jsonwebtoken in my API.
So I decided to use the standard way of authenticating using the token sent by AAD

Comment: This link maybe helpful: https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad#52-bearerstrategy

Comment: @junnas I'm acquiring access_token from the frontend only. And I want to use Bearer Strategy to validate it. Do you its a wrong way?
Right now our API is validated using our own strategy using jsonwebtoken.
But I feel it's an improper way.
What are your suggestions on it?

Comment: @SushantK Did you ever get the BearStrategy approach working?  Currently trying to get it working locally.  I get a valid token from Postman ( log in to Azure etc.. ) and send it along, but always getting the invalid_token error on response.

Answer (score 1):

In case this isn't solved yet, I'm using the OIDCStrategy and it works fine (after also breaking my head over the BearerStrategy first). It returns an access_token in the verify callback that you can plug into your API call. It's in the docs, but you can find a better explanation in the comments if you sift through the module's code itself. Here's my code (work in progress), HTH, would've saved me a lot of headscratching.

```
   const passport = require("passport");
   const OIDCStrategy = require("passport-azure-ad").OIDCStrategy;

var accessToken = "";

app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new OIDCStrategy({
      identityMetadata: process.env.OAUTH_ID_METADATA,
      clientID: process.env.OAUTH_APP_ID,
      responseType: "code id_token",
      responseMode: "form_post",
      redirectUrl: process.env.OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI,
      clientSecret: process.env.OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD,
      scope: "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
      passReqToCallback: true,
      loggingLevel: "info",
      loggingNoPII: false,
    },
 function(req, iss, sub, profile, jwtClaims, access_token, refresh_token, params, done) {
      accessToken = access_token;
      User.findOrCreate({username_1: sub, token: access_token}, function (err, user) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
        return done(null, user, access_token);
      });
    }
  ));
```

Then for the API call:

```
 url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me",
    headers : {
        "Authorization" : "Bearer "+accessToken,
        "Content-Type" : "application/json",
        "Host" : "graph.microsoft.com"
    }
```